# how to add a number to a range of elements in vector very fast

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stl

How do I add a constant `k` to a range of elements`[a,b]` in a vector, really fast!!
The code I've written works well for relatively shorter inputs for `q` number of queries:

```
    long int a,b,k,n;
    vector<long int> v(n+1,0);
    for( long int i=0; i<q ;i++)
       {
          cin>>a>>b>>k;
          for(int j=a-1; j<=b-1; j++)
             {
               v[j]+=k;
             }
       }
```

But this is clearly a very slow solution!! The code takes longer for larger values of **k** and **range**
for example `[a,b]=6581237, 9872072` and `k=87106` will take a comparitively longer time to compute.
So is there a faster way to get the job done with a lower time??

**EDIT:** My method gives a timeout for for larger number of queries(10^7) and when ranges reach of the order of 10^7.

Comment: Adding 3.25 million elements to a `vector` via `[]` is not going to take decades. Several seconds, perhaps. Not sure what the problem you've run into is.

Comment: `n` doesn't seem to be initialized before you use it. I recommend updating the question with a [mcve].

Comment: In addition to the comment by @user4581301 please show which parts of the code you are timing and *how* you are performing that timing.

Comment: [Adding a value to a vector for millions of elements does not take decades](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe99340bb53e5ce4). That example is compiled with no optimizations.  The "Done" message is output after maybe a second or so.  I think you've been a victim of premature optimization.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. What is your original problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have `Q` queries and for each query, you need to add a number to each element in a range of an array. That explains why you think doing so on a vector with a few million elements will take too long, since doing it once would take less than a second.

What you need is a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree), or a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) with lazy propagation, which allows you to update a range of elements or query the value of an element in logarithmic time. A segment tree can also perform range queries in logarithmic time.

A Fenwick tree by itself can perform point updates and prefix sum queries, but we can make it do range updates and point queries using the following:

```
//Add val to every element in [left, right]:
update(left, val);
update(right + 1, -val);

//Query the value at index x:
query(x);
```

For the segment tree solution, you're going to need [lazy propagation](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/segment-tree-and-lazy-propagation/) to perform range updates.

I think the Wikipedia pages might be a little confusing if you're learning them for the first time, so here are some tutorials from hackerearth.com:

- Fenwick tree: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/fenwick-binary-indexed-trees/tutorial/
- Segment tree: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/segment-trees/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

How many *overlapping* intervals do you have/expect?

If ranges are quite large, there are quite some chances that they *do* overlap. For all of these overlaps, you calculate the addition multiple times. Imagine following situation:

```
[10; 100] + 20
[30;  50] - 10
[40; 120] + 10
```

You might resolve the overlaps such that you have only one addition per element (of course, you need to query the ranges *before* doing any calculations then, storing them in some appropriate data structure):

```
[ 10;  30] + 20
[ 30;  40] + 10
[ 40;  50] + 20
[ 50; 100] + 30
[100; 120] + 10
```

As now having independent ranges, you might additionally parallelise the additions (e. g. by placing the ranges in a queue and let each thread take one from as soon as it has finished its previous one – queue needs to be protected against race conditions).